# ``personality(2)`` in Python 2

Tags: linux, python-2.7, system-calls

I need a way of calling `personality(2)` from a Python 2.7 program.
I couldn’t find a mention in the cpython source tree, where would I
start looking? Doing raw syscalls would be acceptable, as long as it
doesn’t add any dependencies.

*Background*:
I have a stubborn library called by a legacy program that I can only
patch around in the Python wrapper part. (Don’t ask.) Unfortunately
that library’s behavior depends on the result of `uname -m`. The
environment this runs in is *very* constrained, so we can’t assume
ordinary userland to be present. (It’d be fine if I could just wrap
the script invocation in `setarch(8)` but that’s just not feasible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with ctypes, which is part of Python and so doesn't add any dependencies:

```
import ctypes

personality = ctypes.CDLL(None).personality
personality.restype = ctypes.c_int
personality.argtypes = [ctypes.c_ulong]

print(personality(0xffffffff))
```